# NHibernate Error :s

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, compilation, compiler-errors

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening?
Ive been trying for about three hours but can't make it work.
Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Net.Http`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.aspx) comes with .Net framework 4.5, Your current application target is .Net framework 4.0, that is why it can't get resolved. Changed your target framework to 4.5.

Comment: But the project is in 4.0.. Ideas on how I can change the system.net.http to 4.0 @habib?

Comment: @user2862542, you have to change the target framework of your application/project. You can't use `System.Net.Http` with .Net framework 4.0